# Select no distingue null de cero

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una tabla con un campo "`estado`" con valores "`null`", "`0`" y "`1`".
Mi query es sencilla:

```
SELECT * FROM "tabla" WHERE estado<>1.
```

- La consulta me devuelve sólo los campos con valor de "`estado`" cero.
- El `null` no lo filtra como distinto de 1.
- La BD no es mía y no puedo hacer que esos campos "null" desaparezcan.

Comment: ¿Qué gestor usas?

Comment: Que tipo de campo es "estado"? a malas, has probado not in, o in (null, 0)?

Comment: El tipo es tinyint.

Comment: El gestor es SQL Managment Studio 2014

Comment: Las únicas comparaciones con null que te va a aceptar son "is not null" o "is null". Te recomendaría "SELECT * FROM "tabla" WHERE estado<>1 or estado is null".

Comment: admite futuras opciones ese campo aparte del 0/1/null? si es así... puedes también hacerlo con subconsultas

Comment: Lograste solucionarlo, creo que con un ISNULL(CAMPO,0)<>1 Funcionaria pruebalo y si te ayuda te ponga la respuesta y el como funciona

Comment: Sipi, como dijo Hermes, null no es igual o no igual a nada, ni siquiera null.  (Es decir null = null es falso.)

Comment: Gracias Hermes. Tu solución funciona correctamente.

Answer (score 2):

La condición sí detecta a `NULL` como distinto de `0`. El problema es que al incluir `NULL` en las comparaciones, pasamos de una lógica binaria a una lógica con 3 posibles resultados: Verdadero, Falso y Desconocido. Cualquier comparación que incluya 'NULL' regresará desconocido y eso es lo que está regresando la condición.

Siempre será preferible comparar con una igualdad que con una desigualdad. Por lo que te sugiero que tu SELECT quede de la siguiente manera.

```
SELECT * 
FROM tabla 
WHERE estado = 0;
```

Dejo también una prueba sencilla con distintas posibilidades de como comparar valores nulos.

```
CREATE TABLE tabla( estado bit NULL)
INSERT INTO tabla VALUES(0), (1), (NULL);

SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE estado <> 1;
SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE estado <> 0;
SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE estado = 1;
SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE estado = 0;
SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE estado <> NULL;
SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE estado = NULL;
SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE estado IS NULL;
SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE estado IS NOT NULL;
```

Siempre es preferible también, tener multiples condiciones unidas en vez de aplicar funciones u operaciones a las columnas del filtro, ya que eso evita la posibilidad de usar índices o estadísticas disponibles y se lee la tabla completa.

```
SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE estado <> 1 OR estado IS NULL;
```